# Как организовать переносимость настроек в админке Voyager (интересует relationships)

Tags: php, laravel, relation

Установил админку Voyager в проект на Laravel, реализую теги, создаю модель Tag, выставляю релейшены в админке, но при командной работе мои изменения не вносятся автоматически (не появляются связи, их надо вручную вносить, после очередного обновления, у всех остальных). Как решить проблему переносимости? Не добавлять же запись каких то данных при каждом чихе в отдельную миграцию. И с меню такие же проблемы, но там то понятно, а вот отношения выставлять вручную это что-то уже непонятное. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Мой коллега решил это таким образом:

Создал команды для artisan по документации https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan, назвал их SaveConfig и LoadConfig вызываются соответственно php artisan voyager:load и php artisan voyager:load. Этими командами он сохраняет содержимое таблиц, где сидят релейшены и пункты меню и прочие необходимости в файл (который и коммитится) и загружает его при необходимости. Вот файлы из projectname/app/Console/Commands:

[SaveConfig](https://pastebin.com/8Sr4i1ak)
[LoadConfig](https://pastebin.com/KMZDx0pQ)

Теперь после того как вы забрали изменения из репозитория, надо выполнить миграции, если они есть и выполнить загрузку изменений Voyager другим разработчиком. Я для удобства включил в секцию composer.json файла скрипт для выполнения этих, пока двух, действий одной командой, вдруг список будет расти.